# Regex Question: how do I replace a single space with a newline in VI

Tags: regex, vim

Regex Question: how do I replace a single space with a newline in VI.

Comment: What's your first guess? It's probably right.

Comment: (Or maybe not... I think I was wrong too.)

Answer (score 8):

`:%s/ /^V^M/g`

note: hit ctrl-v, ctrl-m.

edit: if you really mean all single spaces, meaning spaces not followed by another space, use this:

`:%s/ \{1\}/^V^M/g`

and if you really meant just the first single space in the document, use this:

`:%s/ /^V^M/`

Comment: er... actually, that was a mistake... should be #2 above.

Comment: Thanks again. I will save it for future reference. :%s/ /^V^M/
 is all I need.

Comment: you might just want to forget it actually, it's not correct either... but ^V^M is what you're really looking for :)

Comment: You can also type ^v<enter>, and it will insert the control character you want.  I also use it to search for tabs (^v<tab>).

Answer (score 5):

Just do the following in command mode:

```
:%s/ /\r/gic
```

gic in the end means:
- g: replace all occurrences in the same line (not just the first).
- i: case insensitive (not really helpful here but good to know).
- c: prompt for confirmation (nice to have to avoid you having to do immediate undo if it goes  wrong :) ).

Comment: i modifier? afraid you'll miss some lowercase spaces?

Comment: This will replace all spaces on all lines.  The question asked for a single space, which would be  `:s/ /\r/`

Comment: @ithcy, what, you've never used case sensitive whitespace? It's much more powerful. Think of the impact of a capital tab versus 4 lowercase spaces - a completely different emotional message to your code!

Comment: :1,$s/ /\n/g - replaces space with "n"
:1,$s/ /\r/g  - replaces space with "r"

Comment: @jball: good point. i am using capital spaces for emphasis here.

Comment: @icthcy, they are a very interesting counterpoint to your completely lowercase text.

Comment: Lol, didn't think the 'i' was going to generate such controversy. :P

Answer (score 0):

`\([^ ]\|^\)\([^ ]\|$\)` will find lone spaces only if that's what you need.